# How to push to array of object based on condition?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I am trying to push responses to array based on a conditional statement. The response is in request `details` object it would be nested object with different `LOBS` so it could be both or one lob object in the request. If both lobs are present it works fine. However, when I pass just one `combineResponse` method the code is failing because one of the `arguments` is not passed. How can I resolve this issue or better yet, is there a better approach to handle this?

**main.ts**

```
 private async execute(@Request() request: ExpressRequest): Promise<any> {
        let _combineData: any = [];
        const accountBalanceRequest = request.body.getAccountBalanceRequest;
        const LOB = accountBalanceRequest.details.lineofBusiness;
        let _dataAdmin: any = {};
        let _dataUser: any = {};
        try {
            if (LOB === "ADMIN") {
                _dataAdmin = await this.Admin.adminRequestHandler(accountBalanceRequest);
            }
            if (LOB === "USER") {
                _dataUser = await this.User.userRequestHanlder(request);
            }
            const combinedResponses = this.combineResponse(_dataAdmin, _dataUser, request);
            _combineData = combinedResponses;
        } catch (err) {
            return err;
        }
        return _combineData;
    }


    private combineResponse(AdminResponse: any, UserResponse: any, request: any): any {
            const combinedResponses: any = [];
            let finalResponse: any = {};
            const refID: string = request.body.header.serviceContext.refID;
            const tokenID: string = request.body.header.serviceContext.tokenID;

            combinedResponses.push(AdminResponse, UserResponse);
            if (AdminResponse.header.statusCode === "0000" && UserResponse.header.statusCode === "0000") {
                finalResponse = {
                    getAccountBalanceResponse: {
                        header: request.body.header),
                        details: combinedResponses
                    }
                };
            }

            if (AdminResponse.header.statusCode !== "0000" && UserResponse.header.statusCode !== "0000") {
                finalResponse = {
                    getAccountBalanceResponse: {
                        header: {
                            statusCode: "9999",
                            statusDesc: "partial Error",
                            refID,
                            tokenID
                        },
                        details: combinedResponses
                    }
                };
            }

            return finalResponse;
    }
```

Comment: Please give more information on issue. With examples.

Answer (score 0):

You need a default value or a check for null or undefined.
Try:

```
 private async execute(@Request() request: ExpressRequest): Promise<any> {
        let _combineData: any = [];
        const accountBalanceRequest = request.body.getAccountBalanceRequest;
        const LOB = accountBalanceRequest.details.lineofBusiness;
        let _dataAdmin: any;
        let _dataUser: any;
        try {
            if (LOB === "ADMIN") {
                _dataAdmin = await this.Admin.adminRequestHandler(accountBalanceRequest);
            }
            if (LOB === "USER") {
                _dataUser = await this.User.userRequestHanlder(request);
            }
            const combinedResponses = this.combineResponse(_dataAdmin, _dataUser, request);
            _combineData = combinedResponses;
        } catch (err) {
            return err;
        }
        return _combineData;
    }
    private combineResponse(AdminResponse: any, UserResponse: any, request: any): any {
            const combinedResponses: any = [];
            let finalResponse: any = {};
            const refID: string = request.body.header.serviceContext.refID;
            const tokenID: string = request.body.header.serviceContext.tokenID;

            if (AdminResponse) {
                combinedResponses.push(AdminResponse);
            }
            if (UserResponse) {
                combinedResponses.push(UserResponse);
            }

            if (AdminResponse.header.statusCode === "0000" && UserResponse.header.statusCode === "0000") {
                finalResponse = {
                    getAccountBalanceResponse: {
                        header: request.body.header),
                        details: combinedResponses
                    }
                };
            }

            if ((!AdminResponse || AdminResponse.header.statusCode !== "0000") || (!UserResponse || UserResponse.header.statusCode !== "0000")) {
                finalResponse = {
                    getAccountBalanceResponse: {
                        header: {
                            statusCode: "9999",
                            statusDesc: "partial Error",
                            refID,
                            tokenID
                        },
                        details: combinedResponses
                    }
                };
            }

            return finalResponse;
    }
```

What I did:

1. Removed default assignments for _dataAdmin and _dataUser.
2. Fixed the push to only push values for arguments that are defined.
3. Changed if logic on "partial Error" code block to check if variables are defined first and to return partial error if just one of the statusCodes is wrong(what I think was the intent of the code)

What I assumed:
The await calls return null or undefined if the request fails entirely.

Comment: @cmayard await call return response in both  success and failure cases even its failure i have to push response to combineResponses only issue is when call is only for one LOB how to handle that in combineResponse method

Comment: if one fails thats why i am sending different header with partial error each lob response will have their own header to check if any exception is there